# Mapping objects one to zero

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am trying to map the relation between `Serie` and `Status` using Fluent Api inside `OnModelCreating` method with:

```
serieBuilder.HasOne(x => x.Status)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey<Status>(s => s.SerieId);
```

My models are:

```
public class Serie 
{
   public Guid Id { get; protected set; }
   public Guid UserId { get; protected set; }
   public Status Status {get; protected set; }
}

public class Status 
{
    public Guid Id { get; protected set; }
    public Guid SerieId { get; protected set; }
    public int Active { get; protected set; }
}
```

As the result I can see object with all the fields but Status object (set to null).

I tried few different ways of mapping and I can't get it how I should map it correctly.

Comment: If it's a zero-to-one relationship, it means that it is an optional relationship. You need to use a nullable datatype (in your case it would be `Guid?`)

Comment: If you don't load related data while querying then it will be null. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data for more details.